# Is it possible to program custom tvOS screensavers?

Tags: swift, tvos

I want to know how to create a custom tvOS screensaver. Ideally in Swift. If there is no such thing yet (macOS has ScreenSaverView for example) please tell me if there is another way to create a custom screensaver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that is unfortunately not possible to do today with tvOS. You have to use the built-in ones.